# Cannot pull from GitHub Packages from GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions, ghcr

I am trying to set up a test with pulling from GHCR in GitHub Actions.
According to the docs one shall use `GITHUB_TOKEN`.
So I have the following setup:

```yaml
name: CI
on: push

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: read
    steps:
      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: pull
        run: |
          docker pull ghcr.io/username/terraform-provider-skopeo/alpine:latest
```

Output of these steps are:

```
Logging into ghcr.io...
Login Succeeded!
```

and

```
Error response from daemon: unauthorized
```

Not really sure where the problem with authorization comes from.

Answer (score 3):

You actually need to explicitly give the Repo's Actions permission: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/managing-github-packages-using-github-actions-workflows/publishing-and-installing-a-package-with-github-actions#upgrading-a-workflow-that-accesses-ghcrio

Necessary steps are:

- Navigate to your package landing page.
- In the left sidebar, click Actions access. "Actions access" option in left menu

  To ensure your container package has access to your workflow, you must add the repository where the workflow is stored to your container. Click Add repository and search for the repository you want to add.
- "Add repository" button

  Note: Adding a repository to your container through the Actions access menu option is different than connecting your container to a repository. For more information, see "Ensuring workflow access to your package" and "Connecting a repository to a package."
- Optionally, using the "role" drop-down menu, select the default access level that you'd like the repository to have to your container image.
  Permission access levels to give to repositories
- Open your workflow file. On the line where you log in to ghcr.io, ensure to use `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` (replace PAT).

**Note**: Just linking the Package with the Repo is not enough.